# Find the ip address of hp laser jet 3050

Tags: network-printer, laser-printer, hp-laserjet

I have got a HP Laser Jet 3050 printer, which is connected to the internet and shared by a group of people. It works well with other people but while I am trying to install it on my XP system the problem occurs.

I need the IP address of this printer. I have tried to let the printer print the information out itself, but I failed (there are 'Usage page','Service Page','Self Test/Configuration Page', but none of them have the IP info I needed).

So does anybody got any idea about what should I do?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm stumped. I don't have the printer, but the manual makes it look like you have to configure the IP from the PC, which is strange if you don't yet know the IP!

Comment: @Azz (In those situations, I believe setup programs send a special broadcast message on the local subnet to find the IPs of all matching devices.)

Comment: Is this printer connected directly to the network via ethernet or through the parallel port to a [JetDirect](http://imgur.com/RLcQuzi) box?

Answer (score 1):

On the printer, press the menu/enter button, 
press arrow to the right to "reports",
press the menu/enter button, 
press arrow to the right to "usage",
press menu/enter button.

The printer should automatically print a self-test/configuration page, where I believe the IP address is included.

Comment: The manual suggests you print the **Config report** from the **Reports** menu to find the IP address. (See [HP LaserJet 3050 User Guide](http://bizsupport.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00495173/c00495173.pdf) → How do I? → Network → Set up the all-in-one and use it on the network.)

Comment: thanks for your answer,i have tried again step by step exactly by your instruction.But the IP address is not included indeed.

Comment: Did it print one or two pages?